# Is it secure to use firebase tokens for authentication between my server and an application?

Tags: django, firebase, security, pyrebase

I'm thinking about using firebase to authenticate users. Users could sign up via a pyqt app. Their email address and password would be sent via a POST request to my server (Django). On my server, I would use firebase (pyrebase) to sign them up. I would then store the firebase token in the database on my server, and also return the token to the user and save it there locally. Afterwards, I would always (or until the user logs in again which would return a new token) use this token to authenticate the user and let them access my database. Would this be secure? Something like this:

### On sign-up:

#### User:

```
token = requests.post(url, {"email": email, "pwd": pwd)
```

#### Server:

```
response = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, pwd)
token = response['idToken']
c.execute('INSERT INTO Tabel (email, token) VALUES(?, ?)', (email, token))
return token
```

### After sign-up:

#### User:

```
some_data = requests.post(url, {"token": token, "email": email)
```

#### Server:

```
token_in_database = c.execute("SELECT token FROM Tabel WHERE email = (?)", (email,)).fetchone()
if token == token_in_database:
    return some_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is somewhat similar to what Firebase does with its Authentication tokens, so it can indeed work quite well.  :)

A few things to keep in mind:

- Be sure to only send the credentials from the client to the server, and the ID token from the server to the client, over a secure connection. This reduces the chance of a man-in-the-middle gaining access to either the credentials or the token.
- If you want the authentication state of the user to be available to other Firebase products, don't forget to [sign the user in with the custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) on the client.
- Do you really need to store the token in your database? The Firebase servers do typically not do this, and instead [verify the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) when they first get it. They *do* cache the verification state locally, but there's no central database of current ID tokens which helps scalability.
- You'll want the token to have a reasonably short expiration time, just in case a malicious actor gets access to it. Firebase itself uses ID tokens that are valid for 1 hour, and the SDKs automatically renew then after about 55 minutes.
- If you want a shorter or longer lifetime for your tokens, consider [using a session cookie](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) which can be valid anywhere from 5 minutes to 2 weeks.

Comment: Alright, thanks! All I really want to do with Firebase is authenticate users, so I don't have to store and passwords and email addresses myself. So why would I want the tokens to have a short expiration date?

Comment: While SSL protects you from a most man-in-the-middle attacks, there still is a chance someone uses a badly protected network with faulty certificates, and thus a a malicious actor can get access to the ID token in that case. Since the ID tokens are bearer tokens, they can be used by anyone who has them. Giving them a short expiration time, ensures that at least the time-frame the malicious user has access with *that* specific token is limited.